# How to execute a host autohotey combination/script from within VMware VM?

Tags: autohotkey, vmware-workstation

I have:

- Deepin OS as a VM in VMware workstation pro 15
- Windows 10 as my main OS
- A script at my main OS so that when I click left control + left arrow / right arrow, it switches between workspaces

From inside VM (Deepin OS), that doesn't work. How do I get it to work?

Comment: Write a script that remotes into your host to execute the switch. Usually you have tight restrictions in regards to direct keyboard and mouse movements being send from a guest to the host (for good reason).